# Copy between tmux windows on a server from emacs

Tags: tmux, emacs, clipboard

I am using emacs in one of my tmux windows on a server, when I yank within emacs (say c-k) text how do I make it available to other tmux windows.
Cmd-c and cmd-v have buffers of my laptop.

I would like a way to yank text from emacs and paste it in another tmux window if possible

Comment: Is Emacs running on the same machine as tmux, or are you running Emacs over SSH? If you're using Emacs remotely, consider using it locally instead: Emacs can edit remote files transparently.

Comment: The problem is with the way the server is configured. Tramp doesn't work, I cannot use emacs locally.